# Firebase Notifications value returned for deleted (collapsed) messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm migrating a GCM project to Firebase and now I've got my head around when `onMessageReceived` works, I'm trying to figure out how to handle this situation as per Firebase documentation;

> *There is a limit of 100 messages that can be stored without collapsing. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. When the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The app can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync from the app server.*

My existing code for GCM works and picks up the special message like this;

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {

    // Pick up various parameters here
    String nhMSG0124 = bundle.getString("information");
    ...

   // Check for special message when limit of 100 messages         
   // that can be stored without collapsing is exceeded
   // message_type value is always the string "deleted_messages"
   // total_deleted value is a string with the number of deleted messages

    String gcm_message_type = bundle.getString("message_type");
    String gcm_total_deleted = bundle.getString("total_deleted");
    if (gcm_message_type... 
                            do something else here
```

I've had no success finding anything in FCM documentation so far, however I guess the code will look something like this, just not sure what the deleted messages function is or whether the flag is in the notification itself or in the data;

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String nhMSG0124 = remoteMessage.getData().get("information");
    ...
    String gcm_message_type = remoteMessage.get...  what.?    ("message_type");
    String gcm_total_deleted = remoteMessage.get... what.?     ("total_deleted");
    if (gcm_message_type ...etc...
```

Has anyone else figured this out..?

Any help appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have this sorted. Re-read Firebase documentation, it looks like message deletion causes a MESSAGING_EVENT as below, whereas GCM used special parameters in the notification bundle.

```
public void onDeletedMessages ()
    then do process...

    Called when GCM server deletes pending messages due to exceeded storage limits, 
    for example, when the device cannot be reached for an extended period of time.
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

Tested app and verified as solved..!